# Double vertical bars alongside statements of theorems

Tags: theorems, rules

Prof. Hatcher describes a way to produce them in TeX here:

http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/typography.html

I would like to know if any of you guys knows of a way to generate them in LaTeX.

I thank you in advance for your insightful replies...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be easily achieved with the [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}
\surroundwithmdframed[outerlinewidth=0.4pt,
  innerlinewidth=0.4pt,
  middlelinewidth=1pt,
  middlelinecolor=white,
  bottomline=false,topline=false,rightline=false]{theo}

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}
\lipsum[4]
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A simple variation of the above code produces a double ruled frame:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}
\surroundwithmdframed[outerlinewidth=0.4pt,
  innerlinewidth=0.4pt,
  middlelinewidth=1pt,
  middlelinecolor=white]{theo}

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}
\lipsum[4]
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

[image]