# Creating a particular environment with a left-side rule

Tags: environments, theorems, rules

I don't have much experience in creating environments, and my understanding of them allows me to create environments which do something at the beginning and at the end (like for instance, in a "proof" environment, I can begin it with "Proof." and end it with a little square in the bottom right.

What I want to do now is slighty more complicated (so it seems to me), I just want something looking like

```
Proof.
|
|
| content here
|
|
| end of proof
```

I want those vertical dashes to be a straight line from bottom to top. Any way I could be able to do that?

Comment: I think you'll be able to find a solution using [`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed), since it allows even for page breaking and setting particular borders. In that regard, see [Double vertical bars alongside statements of theorems](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/81991/5764).

Comment: @Werner It's a good start, but the problem is that instead of putting a line where the text should be and pushing the text to the right, it puts a line to the left of the text, which is not quite what I want to do. Do you think we could tweak it so that it works?

Comment: Yes, things can be modified. In your image, it shows that you have the vertical rule flush with the left margin and the `content here` pushed to the right. That's exactly what the link does (see the image in the [linked answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81993/5764) when you add some text before/after the `theo` environment). You don't want that?

Comment: @Werner : I tried what the link said, and it compiled well, but the vertical rule is to the left of the left margin, and the text is where it would've been if I had done nothing particular. It doesn't show as in the image, although if for instance I would remove the "bottomline=false,...," part of the code, it would surround the whole text with a box.

Comment: Should I modify the position of the left margin inside the environment to fix the problem? (I don't know how to do that by the way, that's why I ask.)

Comment: OH!!! Nevermind, it works. It's just because I was comparing the margins with the wrong things ; I had only written environment titles when I was testing environment, and all the titles were a little bit flushed to the right... gave me an illusion. It does work! Great thanks. (I'd be happy to accept your answer if you posted it.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a slight modification of [Double vertical bars alongside statements of theorems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/81991/5764) to accommodate for the layout of your `proof` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{proof}
  {\par\noindent\normalfont\textbf{Proof.}\par\nopagebreak%
  \begin{mdframed}[
     linewidth=1pt,
     linecolor=black,
     bottomline=false,topline=false,rightline=false,
     innerrightmargin=0pt,innertopmargin=0pt,innerbottommargin=0pt,
     innerleftmargin=1em,% Distance between vertical rule & proof content
     skipabove=.5\baselineskip
   ]}
  {\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{proof}
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{proof}
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Margin adjustments in [`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) allows for a block that spans page breaks. See the [`mdframed` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf) for more options (including colours, if needed).

Since you're using a vertical rule to define the scope of the `proof` environment, I don't think it's necessary to add anything else.