# Redefine theorem environment to have vertical line

Tags: environments, theorems

I want to redefine the Theorem environment so that there is a vertical line on the left side of the content of \begin{theorem} \end{theorem}, except for the first line. I have no idea how to do it or if I need a new package besides AMS's.

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101507/82917

Comment: You should be able to do it with `mdframed`, but I don't understand precisely what you mean by "except for the first line". Can you mock up a desired output? Also, are you already using some theorem packages, like `amsthm` or `ntheorem`? It would be helpful to make your constraints clear.

Comment: @campa 's comment basically answers my question, but I would prefer that the text started right after Proof, not in the next line. That is what I mean by "except for tyhe first line". The word Proof (or Theorem etc) on the first line, and from the second line onwards a left-side rule just as in tex.stackexchange.com/q/101507/8291

Comment: I use the package amsthm