# Une décoration avec latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]
Bonjour, comment faire des courbes comme ça, merci de votre aide, J'ai déjà parcouru les messages sans aucune solution, je ne veux pas que vous le fassiez pour moi mais juste des suggestions comme dans ce poste :
[Reproduce the vertical margins below the environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493654/reproduce-the-vertical-margins-below-the-environment)

Quand a la lange de communication n'est pas importante puisque la traduction s'obtient par un clic , ありがとうございました

Comment: Hi and welcome. To ask questions in French, it's here: https://texnique.fr/osqa/

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This is not a "do it for me" kind of site. If you want people to help you, provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). To do so, you can start looking at the [TikZ package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Answer (score 1):

Il s'agit d'un forum anglophone, un post en anglais serait plus adapté.
De plus, je pense qu'il s'agit d'une image sur laquelle le texte a été écrit.
Pour inclure une image, la méthode expliquée en français est ici 
https://www.xm1math.net/doculatex/insertionimages.html

À vérifier avec des utilisateurs plus expérimentés de `tikz-pgf`.

---

**This is an English-speaking forum, an English post would be more suitable.
In addition, I think it is an image on which the text was written.
To include an image, the method explained in French is here** https://www.xm1math.net/doculatex/insertionimages.html

**Check with more experienced `tikz-pgf` users AND CHECK THE DOCUMENTATION PACKAGE**

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[<your scale>]{<your image (.) the format>}
\caption{<as you want>}
\label{<as you want>}
\end{figure}
```