# Highlight a postulate with an indicator on the margin

Tags: formatting, margins, marginnote

Currently I have a created a postulate environment that works as follows,

```
\vspace{1em}
\begin{postulate}\label{section:Schrodinger}
    {\bfseries{\textsc{(Schr\"odinger) }}} Time translation is given by, $\rho\mapsto e^{-itH}\rho e^{itH}.$
\end{postulate}
\vspace{1em}
```

Yields a result,

[image]

Now what I want to do is highlight or make the reader focus on this statement by doing some indicator type diagram on the margin as follows,

[image]

Comment: You can use the `leftbar` environment from the `framed` package. I suppose `postulate` is define as a theorem-like environment?

Comment: @Bernard Yes it's theorem like environment. Can you elaborate a bit on what I should do? Also I want it to align correctly with the text. If the text is larger it should be correctly sized. Bigger text => Longer indicator on the margin

Comment: Seems like framed and some other package I am using are in conflict

Comment: You can do that either with `thmtools` or with `ntheorem`. Could you please post  a complete code showing how exactly you defined this environment?

Comment: @Bernard My sty file is a bit of a clusterfuck. Too many things defined there. I believe this is my definition for postulate. 
\newtheorem*{postulate}{\textsc{Postulate}}

Would it be possible to do this as a margin note and tikz?

Comment: Related/duplicate(s): [Creating a particular environment with a left-side rule](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101507/5764); [Double vertical bars alongside statements of theorems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/81991/5764)

Comment: Thank you @Werner but this one seems to be within the text? I wanted to do this in the margin so that it's not uniform like rest of the paper and would draw some attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variant solution which use the `tcolorbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[theorems,skins]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbtheorem{postulate}{Postulate}{
description delimiters parenthesis,
separator sign ={.},
coltitle=black,
colback=white,
fontupper=\itshape,
fonttitle=\upshape\bfseries,
attach title to upper={\ },
empty,
left*=0pt,
right*=0pt,
boxsep=0pt,
top=1em,
bottom=1em,
borderline west={2mm}{-5mm}{blue} 
}{section}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{postulate*} {Heisenberg} 
   Time translation is given by, $\rho\mapsto e^{-itH}\rho e^{itH}.$
   \lipsum[1]
\end{postulate*}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{postulate} {Schr\"odinger}{Schrodinger}
   Time translation is given by, $\rho\mapsto e^{-itH}\rho e^{itH}.$
   \lipsum[2]
\end{postulate}
\textcolor{red}{See} the postulate \ref{section:Schrodinger}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is this causing a conflict? Possibly with the package amsthm

Comment: @Boltzee What conflict ?

Comment: It was having some conflict with \label but that was fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Is that what You wanted? If not visit this [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66820/how-to-create-highlight-boxes-in-latex)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
% As I am working with transparency here, you should define darker colors.
\definecolor{colorBackground}{HTML}{F5F5F5} % Grey 500
\definecolor{colorDefinition}{HTML}{4CAF50} % Green 500
\definecolor{colorNotiz}{HTML}{81D4FA}      % Light Blue 200

\mdfdefinestyle{box}{
    topline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    rightline=false,
    linewidth=4pt,
    backgroundcolor=none,
    apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfbackground/.append style={fill=gray!45,fill opacity=.6}}},
    frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries\color{black},
    splittopskip=.5cm,
    frametitlebelowskip=0.0cm,
}

% Definition
\mdtheorem[style=box,linecolor=colorDefinition]{Def}{Postulate}



\begin{document}
\begin{Def}
$$\rho\mapsto e^{-itH}\rho e^{itH}.$$
\end{Def}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, what I am trying to do is a blue-green line in the margin not within the text